# 1-Wasserstein distance between distributions over discrete alphabet

Tags: probability

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distributions over discrete alphabet with support in $[0,1]$.
Let $W(p,q)$ be the 1-Wasserstein distance with respect to $L^1$ between the two distributions.
I want to bound $W(p,q)$ from above.

When the alphabet is continuous, I was able to show that $W(p,q)\leq 1$ for any such $p$ and $q$, using the closed-form expression for the 1-Wsaaeratein distance (cumulative function representation).
However, for discrete alphabet, this does not seems to be working.
Is there a different bound for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, let $\mathcal{X}$ the (finite) alphabet. Then the 1-Wasserstein distance between two distributions is:
$$W_1(p,q)=\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}|F_p(x)-F_q(x)|$$
where $F_p(\cdot)\in[0,1]$ and $F_q(\cdot)\in[0,1]$ are the cdf of $p(\cdot)$ and $q(\cdot)$ respectively. Then you can bound $W_1(p,q)\leq|\mathcal{X}|$.